# Unit Test in Java of a Guava Function used to trasform two objects with same fields

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have a very specific use case, that occurs every time you have two objects from classes `A` and `B`, respectively, characterized of having the same non-static fields and you want to transform one in the other. I personally use [`Function`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html) from Guava, as follows:

```
public class A{
  private static serialVersionUID = ....

  private int field1;
  private String field2;
}

public class B{
  private int field1;
  private String field2;

  public B(final int field1, final String field2){
    this.field1 = field1;
    this.field2 = field2;
  }
}

public class AToBTransformer implements Function<A, B> {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public B apply(final A aObj) {
      return new B(a.field1, a.field2);
    }

}
```

Now, in the unit test I can check if the `AToBTransformer` is going to return an instance of `B` with the same values of the instance of `A` in all the common non-static fields. I mean, they should provide the same mapping in all the future version of the code, so if one field is added in `A` then it should be provided also in `B`.

Is there any reasonable way to check that **automatically** in the unit test?

I was thinking about counting the number of fields, or using reflection to campare them, but I'm not sure that this is the best approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unitils library support the reflection based field comparison**:

```
ReflectionAssert.assertReflectionEquals("message", expected, actual);
```

Comment: Mhhh! I'm not sure that you are using in the right way. The first field should be the fieldName to be compared.

Comment: It is correct. You you sure you are looking at the correct method?

Comment: Yes, youn are right. I was looking one line above. So, It should be correct to retrieve all the fiels using reflection and than checking with that assertion. In that case I can also use Hamcrest ([hasProperty](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/beans/HasPropertyWithValue.html#hasProperty(java.lang.String, org.hamcrest.Matcher))).